# regarding UIImageView Constant Animation

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, core-animation

I have an image I want to animate constantly in UIImageView. Like some image object to move left and right?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't write "urgent" in your question, it's considered rude. You need to write a bit more a specific question. Have you tried coding anything for this already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the animation in a image editor (or something else if you already have the animation)

Then save each frame as an image. Create a folder in your Xcode project and import the files into it. (in the example below each frame is named "frame-x.png" where x is the frame number)

Then create an array of UIImages and set the UIImageView's `animationImages` property to it:

```
imageView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"frame-1"],
                                                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"frame-2"],
                                                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"frame-3"],
                                                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"frame-4"],
                                                        nil];
```

Where you have a UIImage for each frame. You then start the animation:

```
[imageView startAnimation];
```

You can also set the `animationRepeatCount` property of the image view.

See the [UIImageView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for more details.